# Object identifier alone in an object literal

Tags: javascript

An object literal defined with a bare variable identifier (as opposed to a key/value pair) produces an object with a property whose key is the identifier and whose value is the variable's value. Where is this behavior defined in the ECMAScript spec?

```
var variable = 'hi';
var obj = { variable };
console.log(obj.variable);
```

Outputs:

```
hi
```

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5 says *PropertyNameAndValueList* must be in the form of *PropertyName : AssignmentExpression* (note the colon) or be a getter or setter.

Comment: The ECMAScript spec you linked to is version 5. Property shorthands were introduced in version 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the EcmaScript spec for ES5. You need to look at a more recent spec, since ES5 didn't support that.

In the most recent spec you can see it as `IdentifierReference` under `PropertyDefinition`: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer

Comment: I did a jsfiddle with Javascript 1.7 https://jsfiddle.net/smgw1fkq/, and this notation still worked. Is this a bug in jsfiddle or am I misunderstanding Javascript 1.7 to be prior to ES5?

Comment: JavaScript 1.7 is a Mozilla implementation that doesn't follow a specific version of the EcmaScript spec. It has many features that aren't in ES5 and is missing many that are.